# android Activity static starter method in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

In java, one can define a starter static method for an Activity. In Android Studio, there is even a "starter" template for it: it would look something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String EXTRA_FOO = "foo";

    public static void start(Context caller, String bar){
        Intent intent = new Intent(caller, MyActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_FOO, bar);
        caller.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I'm wrapping my head around this same concept in Kotlin and the closest thing I came up with looks like this:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        private val EXTRA_FOO = "foo"

        fun start(caller: Context, bar: String){
            val intent = Intent(caller, MyActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_FOO, bar)
            caller.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more concise and elegant way to do this? I can't believe this is the way to go, it looks uglier than in Java. Also, there is no "starter" template for Kotlin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few approaches you could take. I'm a fan of [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html):

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity()

private fun Intent.extraFoo(bar : String) = putExtra("foo", bar)

fun Context.startMyActivity(bar : String) =
    Intent(this, MyActivity::class.java).apply { extraFoo(bar) }.let(this::startActivity)
```

This creates an extension to `Context` so that you can call `startMyActivity` on any `Context` object.

---

Here's that same extension function in a more Java-like style, so you can compare it more easily to what you already have:

```
private val EXTRA_FOO = "foo"

fun Context.startMyActivity(bar : String) {
    val intent = Intent(this, MyActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_FOO, bar)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: thanks, i like this solution. would you suggest also some other approach?

Comment: but how do u invoke this method from caller activity? I tried your second option.

Comment: @Sam Do you have any suggestion to create Fragments to avoid companion objects?

Comment: @Sam still can't call startMyActivity method cuz extansion doesn't make it static... MyActivity still doesn't have startMyActivity method.

Answer (score 0):

To add onto Sam's approach, I typically use extensions for activities, but in cases like fragments where you need to create a new instance and pass arguments, I may consider the following:

```
class F : Fragment() {
    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(text: String): F {
            val f = F()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString("key", text)
            f.arguments = bundle
            return f
        }

        fun test() {
            //you can now initialize a fragment and put text in its bundle like so
            val f = F("hi")
        }
    }
}
```

The operator function allows you to use the constructor like notation.